# I want to retrieve Firestore data using "where" in Flutter, but I'm getting null as the result

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm retrieving data from a Flutter app using the following code.

```dart
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>> fetchNearbyData({
    required LatLng location,
  }) {
    final response = _firebaseFirestore
        .collection('post')
        .where('status', isEqualTo: 'active');
    return GeoFlutterFire()
        .collection(collectionRef: response)
        .within(
          center: GeoFlutterFire().point(
            latitude: location.latitude,
            longitude: location.longitude,
          ),
          radius: 10,
          field: `location`,
        );
  }

  // [fetchNearbyData] call method
  void fetchData({required LatLng location}) {
    ref
        .watch(fetchNearbyData)
        .fetchNearbyDocumentData(location: location)
        .listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotList) async {
          // save fanction
        });
  }
```

However, the content is returning with `null`. I did create an `index` from the Firestore console, but I still can't retrieve the data. How can I use "where" to retrieve the data?

Comment: What does the code look like where you are waiting for the future?  And are you calling .get() or .snapshots()?

Comment: I won't use .get() and .snapshot().

Comment: Can you show how you call `fetchNearbyData`? We essentially need to see a [minimal, standalone piece of code that completely reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful). Since you say that something is returning `null`, maybe you can `print` that return value and show us *that* code and its output.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @. Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen
I have added a function that calls fetchNearbyData.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a stream, you need to called .snapshots()

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: your function appears to be meant for returning a stream of List of documentsnapshots